# How to create a conditional which checks the value of written text in plain TeX?

Tags: conditionals, plain-tex

I need to create a conditional in plain TeX like this:

```
IF #1 = "N"
THEN
    PRINT "TRUE"
ELSE
    PRINT "#1"
```

I tried various ways in TeX. The solution must be simple, but none of the ways I tried worked, e.g.:

```
\if#1="N"
    N
\else
    #1
\fi
```

There is never any other code inside `#1` when "#1" is set to "N", e.g., `\macro{N}`, it is never `\macro{\emph{N}}`.

How can I create a conditional which checks the value of written text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution 1

`\ifx` compares to macros:

```
\def\charcheckfor{N}
\def\checkfor#1{%
    \def\tempcheckcharfor{#1}%
    \ifx\tempcheckcharfor\charcheckfor%
        true%
    \else%
        false%
    \fi%
}

\checkfor{N}
\checkfor{X}
```

### Solution 2

`\pdfstrcmp` (needs pdfTeX, for other engines there is [`pdftexcmds`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds)) expands to `0` if the strings are equal, to `-1` if the first comes before the second (ASCII character code wise) and to `1` if the first comes after the second.

```
\def\charcheckfor{N}
\def\checkfor#1{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\charcheckfor}=0%
        true%
    \else%
        false%
    \fi%
}
\checkfor{N}
\checkfor{X}
```